# Add TeX path to R Studio - Ubuntu

Tags: path, ubuntu-14.04, tex, sweave

I'm having the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118827/add-tex-distribution-to-path-for-r-studio?):

When I open any .Rnw file, R Studio says that I have no TeX Distribution installed: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 w/ Gnome and TeXLive 2014.

I include the line `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin:${PATH}` in the Renviron.site file, which now looks like:

```
##                      Emacs please make this -*- R -*-
## empty Renviron.site for R on Debian
##
## Copyright (C) 2008 Dirk Eddelbuettel and GPL'ed
##
## see help(Startup) for documentation on ~/.Renviron and Renviron.site

# ## Example ~/.Renviron on Unix
# R_LIBS=~/R/library
# PAGER=/usr/local/bin/less

# ## Example .Renviron on Windows
# R_LIBS=C:/R/library
# MY_TCLTK="c:/Program Files/Tcl/bin"

# ## Example of setting R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES (from R CMD check)
# R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES='utils,grDevices,graphics,stats'
# # this loads the packages in the order given, so they appear on
# # the search path in reverse order.

PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin:${PATH}
```

However the problem persists. How can I fix this and run Sweave or knitR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem, I opened R Studio and checked the pdflatex installation with

```
> Sys.which("pdflatex")
pdflatex 
  ""
```

Which show that it is in fact empty, so I run the command `Sys.getenv("PATH")`to check the current PATH:

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1]   "/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

To add my pdflatex Path, I had to find the `pdflatex` file on my texlive directory, which was `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux`, then I added this to my current Path:

```
> Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux",sep=":"))
```

And now it works perfectly

EDIT: the solution above works only for the open session and is only temporary, you have to run the code everytime you open a new session. I'm still trying to find a permanent solution

Answer (score 2):

see this page: [Customizing Startup](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html), modify this file `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site`, and put your code in this file. It looks like a permanent solution maybe.

===

i saw this file `/etc/environment` is the same as the output of `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, so i think that sys.getenv("PATH") reads file `/etc/environment`.

Therefore the better way is to modify this file `/etc/environment` adding this code `:/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux​`.

after i did it, i tried `source /etc/envronment` and restarted Rstudio, but it didn't work.

Finally it makes sense after i restarted my ubuntu system. ^_^

I hope my poor English expression is clear enough.